# Verifying the solution of the three-dimensional Poisson's equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C}$ be a Schwartz function, then the solution of the three-dimensional Possion's equation
$$\Delta u=f$$
is given by the formula:
$$u(x)=f*K(x)=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|}\,dy,$$
where $K(x)=-\frac{1}{4\pi|x|}$ is the Newton potential and $|x|=(\sum_{j=1}^3 x_j^2)^{1/2}$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$.

Now I need to verify that $u$ satisfies the equation $\Delta u=f$. A direct computation shows that 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}(x_j-y_j)\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^3}\,dy.$$
for $j=1,2,3$.
I have problem in computing the second partial derivative, the hints says 
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)=\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}f(x)-\frac{1}{4\pi}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{|x-y|\geq \varepsilon}\left(\frac{3(x_i-y_i)(x_j-y_j)}{|x-y|^5}-\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x-y|^3}\right)f(y)\,dy$$
for $i,j=1,2,3$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. If we let $i=1,j=2$, then how to show that limit $$\lim_{\varepsilon>0}\int_{|x-y|\geq \varepsilon} \frac{(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)}{|x-y|^5}f(y)\,dy$$ exists? 
And if $i=j$, then the derivative has an additional term $\frac{1}{3}f(x)$, why is it different from $i\neq j$?